# How to write media queries for 480*800 and 480*856 devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new to responsive design and i didn't get it properly till now. My question is that i need to write two media queries for 480*800 and 480*856 device for both landscape and portrait mode. Please explain it to me how it works ?

I have tried this query and it seems working for both the devices in landscape mode

> @media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:854px) and (orientation:landscape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 480px) and (min-height:800px) and (max-height:856px)
{
   body {
      background-color:lime;
   }
}
```

This would target both devices with the same css code.

Alternatively you could split it into two media queries and target each platform.

When I was new to responsive design I found this article very useful: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Is this media query is for portrait mode?

Comment: No its for both portrait and landscape mode. If you want, you can add portrait mode to the query. Just add the following to the query: and (orientation:portrait)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following css styles:

```
media screen (max-width: 480px) and (max-height:856px) {
    //code
}

media screen (max-width: 480px) and (max-height:800px) {
    //code
}

media screen and (max-width: 856px) {
    //code
}

media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    //code
}
```

Comment: i tried the last two queries in landscape mode and its not working